# In cpp how to use getline() get full sentence without interactive input?

Tags: c++

Like the following codes, how to get the whole sentences by getline() function if there is no interactive input?

right now, the input&output is:

input "today is a good day"

output "today"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

string value;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        value=argv[1];
        cout << value;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh? What about actually use `getline()` instead of `operator<<`?

Comment: It's kind of up to the OS/shell (and possibly the startup code) to decide how to parse the command line into `argv`. Most provide some way to keep separate words together in a single argument--enclosing the words in double quotes (as you've shown in the question) is a fairly commonly accepted one.

Comment: Adding to @JerryCoffin's comment, in both Unix-land and Windows you can get at the original command line (or slightly edited version of it) via OS-specific API. In Windows via the `GetCommandLine` function, and in Unix-land as I recall via a pseudo-directory. However, the C++ standard library does not provide this functionality, and so the practical solution is to quote the argument text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
string s;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    s += argv[i];
    s += "   ";
}
```

Comment: Recommend adding in a space to re-separate the arguments.

Comment: yeah sorry i was distructed one sec :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd handle this in the calling environment, by *piping* your input.

```
$ myProgram
<console waiting for input>
```

vs

```
$ echo "my input here!" | myProgram
```

or

```
$ cat /var/someFile | myProgram
```

or even

```
$ netcat 192.168.0.15:80 | myProgram
```

No code changes required.

Command line arguments are intended for switches and options that alter the program's behaviour.